# Why does accessing my object by index give me undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/getTimeData', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log("[+] getTimeData");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data[0]);
        }
    });
```

I have the following output

[image]

As you can see, I am getting undefined. I am trying to access the first element and then if this works, the first element within the nested (but this is for later on)

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Tip : change `success: function (data)` to `success: function (result)` and do `console.log(result)`

Comment: Simply debugging this would of made this obvious, no?

Comment: It's a classic example of over use of variable name `data`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `data.data[0]`?

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '/getTimeData', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log("[+] getTimeData");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.data[0]);
    }
});
```

From your print that's the structure. First, you have an object named `data` with a property with the name `data` that is an array.

```
data (Object)
-- data (Array(5))
---- 0 (Array(4))
---- 1 (Array(4))
---- (...)
```